# how to scroll through array in PHP?

Tags: php

I tried to insert file into array and get a specific result from it.

the `array_search()` doesn't seem to work.

it looks something like this:

```
  $filepath = "/etc/log/20151026.log";
  $logs = file($filepath); 
   $lo = array($logs);  
   $search = array_search("username ",$lo);  
   echo $search;
```

If I echo only the array `$lo` I get the array displayed, yet I can't search through it.

I also tried to extract the array by pieces but a search would be more convenient for the purpose I need.

Comment: Add your array for reference.

Comment: might be space after `username` might not match the word?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. file() returns a string which you wrap in an array and then try to find something in the array other than $logs. Madness. I assume you want to search for something or in some way parse the log file? I think you are asking the wrong question. Ask what you want and give us a snippet of the data you have to work with. You will get way better answers that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **foreach**. It provides an easy way to iterate or scroll over arrays. There are two syntaxes:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)     
statement     
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)    
statement
```